Не перепрошивается ESP32 DEVKITV1
Есть ESP32 DEVKITV1, хочу установить на него Marauder для flipper zero. Скачал прошивку и пытаюсь поставить через flash_download_tool_3.9.7 , выбираю esp-32, developer, в самом приложении нужные файлы, и пробовал все настройки которые есть. Не чего не помогает ошибка "please refer to the chip datasheet and confirm that strapping pins status is correct". Я не очень разбираюсь, буду рад если поможете решить ошибку или предложите другие варианты что можно сделать.
